# facebook post graph action

Tags: facebook, graph

I am trying to post graph action on facebook from my website , but action isnt posted and no error is given by facebook . It's being posted when I am (the admin) is using the website , What can i do with that ? I mean is it permission issue? I am asking for publish_actions on the authentication .

Answer (score 0):

You must submit the action for approval. As long as you haven't sent the action to Facebook only admins can see the open graph post.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/